# writing the word Українська in html page

Tags: html, special-characters, notepad++

Please I'm trying to write the word "**Українська**" in an html page, so I copy it and past it in the notepad++ editor but it gives me "**??????????**"

I think this is an html special character, so please any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that by default Notepad++ uses ANSI, which explains the question marks you're getting.

To switch to UTF-8 mode go to `Encoding > Encode in UTF-8` and then try to paste in the word.

[image: Encode menu screenshot]

Then make sure the HTML page has the meta charset like explained above in the other answers, so it could be viewed properly on the browser:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the encoding of the file is `UTF-8` (`Encoding` menu), that you have the correct `meta` element for this encoding and that the server is returning `UTF-8`.

Comment: When I copy the word and past it on notepad++, it gives me "??????????", so the problem is with notePad++ perhaps ?

Comment: @SamiElHilali - Make sure the file you are pasting it into is a UTF-8 file.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf-8 encoding in html code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Answer (score 0):

a question mark usually replaces undecodable special characters when you encode your special characters with `utf8`, because web browsers by default decode the web page using `iso-latin1`. You should explicitely declare the encoding of your web page using the following directive:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
```

For special characters like this, I prefer to use HTML entities

Answer (score 0):

You can either solve the problems of character encoding in your authoring program, at the HTML level, and in your server (if needed), or you can take the shortcut of using character references, which work independently of encoding. The latter is feasible if you just need, say, one word in Ukrainian on a page otherwise in English. In this case, you can use

```
&#1059;&#1082;&#1088;&#1072;&#1111;&#1085;&#1089;&#1100;&#1082;&#1072;
```

(Constructed by copying the word and pasting it in BabelPad and using the command Convert → Numerical Character References (NCR) → Unicode to NCR (hex).)